# Return previous parameter while calling another function in JS

Tags: javascript

How to achieve the below logic in JS

Example:

```
Let y = alertMyPreviousParam(“1”);

Let z= y(‘2’) 
// show output as  1

Let a = z(‘3’)
// show output as 2

Let b = a(‘ra’) 
// show output as 3

Let c = b(‘z’) 
// show output as ‘ra’,
```

Comment: You have declared `let z= y(‘2’)` and next you are calling `z(‘3’)`. Then how will value of z matches 1? `z` will be a function only. How do you expect the behaviour of function? What have you tried till now?

Answer (score 0):

Despite of various `Syntax error`

**1)** string enclosed by `‘` and `’` is not valid javascript string, similarly with `“` and `”`. Use either `"` or `'`.

**2)** variable should be declared with `let` not `Let`.

---

**SOLUTION**

You can take advantage of `closure` and `Higher order function(HOF)` here

```js
function alertMyPreviousParam(arg) {
  let last = arg;
  return function (curr) {
    console.log(last);
    last = curr;
    return alertMyPreviousParam(curr);
  };
}

let y = alertMyPreviousParam("1");

let z = y("2");
// show output as  1

let a = z("3");
// show output as 2

let b = a("ra");
// show output as 3

let c = b("z");
// show output as ‘ra’,
```

Comment: first we are calling let y = alertMyPreviousParam("1");.... there is no previous param for 1st time.. so it should return undefined right?

Comment: @theblacklinen After the invocation of the `alertMyPreviousParam` function first time, It will return a function

Answer (score 0):

You’ll want to look into closures. Here’s an example:

```
let var = null
let next = null
const myFunc = (newnext) => {
  var = next
  next = newnext
  return var
}
```

Sorry for the formatting, I’m on mobile

Answer (score 0):

the function alertMyPreviousParam, returns a new function, and outputs the previous input. This can be achieved as follows:

```
let alertMyPreviousParam = (x) => (y) => {
  console.log(x);
  return alertMyPreviousParam(y);
}
```